# Finding if a number is divisible by another using %

Tags: python, boolean, division

Using python 3.7, I am trying to determine whether a number is divisible by 5 for a if else statement. This is the code that I have currently that I found from another question on here.

```
x_crest = 162
if x_crest % 5 == 0
    return True 
else:
    return False
```

I have tried converting x_crest to an integer, float and array to no avail. 
I have also tried changing x_crest in the if statment to a value of '162' as shown below.

```
if 162 % 5 == 0
    return True 
else:
    return False
```

This also does not work.

Both return 'invalid syntax' on the `if` line.

At this stage the `return` true/false are placeholders for other functions that will be undertaken depending whether x_crest is divisible by 5.

Many thanks for your help! Please let me know if any more information is required, and what information that might be.

Comment: An if statement has a `:` after the condition, your syntax is indeed invalid.

Comment: As Grismar said, you need `:` after the if conditional. This also applies to `for`, `class`, etc. By the way `return True if 2147483647 % 81 == 0 else False` is better

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a : after your if statement

```
x_crest = 162
if x_crest % 5 == 0:
    return True 
else:
    return False
```